# Python combine numpy arrays with indices

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3]).reshape(1, 4)
arr2 = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).reshape(1, 6)
arr3 = np.array([0, 1, 4, 3, 5]).reshape(1, 5)
list_off_arrs = [arr1, arr2, arr3]
# expected output:
# ndarray -> [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 13, 15]]
```

I want to take a list of numpy arrays that are all one dimensional and contain index values, and combine them as shown above. Is there a quick way to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3]).reshape(1, 4)
arr2 = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).reshape(1, 6)
arr3 = np.array([0, 1, 4, 3, 5]).reshape(1, 5)
list_of_arrs = [arr1, arr2, arr3]

n = len(list_of_arrs)
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i):
        list_of_arrs[i] += list_of_arrs[j].shape[1]
print(np.hstack(list_of_arrs))
```

Result:

```
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 14 13 15]]
```

Comment: This works exactly how I need it besides the result is a list of arrays. Can you update it so it produces just one array? (Not in a list, just one array of all numbers).

Comment: @SzJYn6Qg Sorry, I pasted the wrong line. See my latest edit

Answer (score 0):

Use `numpy.concatenate`

```
>>> arr2 += arr1[0, -1] + 1
>>> arr3 += arr2[0, -1] + 1
>>> np.concatenate([arr1, arr2, arr3], axis=1)
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 14, 13, 15]])
```

Comment: The amount of arrays in the list varies, the code should be based on the one list.